# Django: cannot import name WebApi

Tags: python, django

I'm tring to import the shodan api library in my Django application with:

```
from shodan import WebAPI
```

The library was installed with easy_install and if I import and use it from python prompt it works fine.

Any help?

Comment: did you put shodan in your installed_app in settings.py?

Comment: No, what should I add to INSTALLED_APPS?

Answer (score 1):

For example in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.humanize',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.markup',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.admindocs',


'shodan',
]
```

Comment: No I did not add it to the INSTALLED_APPS because shodan is an external third party library (https://github.com/achillean/shodan-python) not an application made by me.

Comment: even if it is third party or made by you, it is required to put that in install app in settings. But most of the apps not all, just try it to know the output